# How to bind ssl cert created in the cli to functionapp from az cli

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I want to make a script which will make a functionapp, create a subdomain on my existing domain and make it SSL secure. My problem is that I can't bind the SSL cert to the functionapp from the cli. To get to where I am now I've executed these commands:

#### Setup

```
az functionapp create -g {resource-group} --consumption-plan-location eastus --runtime python --runtime-version 3.11 --functions-version 4 --name {function_name} --os-type linux --storage-account {storage}

## Running this will give an error but it gives the value of the following command
az functionapp config hostname add --hostname {subdomain}.{existing_domain} --name {function_name} -g {resource-group}

az network dns record-set txt add-record -g {domain_resource_group} -z {existing_domain} -n asuid.{subdomain} --value {secret_from_previous_step}
az network dns record-set cname create -g {domain_resource_group} -z {existing_domain} -n {subdomain}
az network dns record-set cname set-record -g {domain_resource_group} -z {existing_domain} --record-set-name {subdomain} --cname {function_name}.azurewebsites.net

az functionapp config hostname add --hostname {subdomain}.{existing_domain} --name {function_name} -g {resource-group}


az functionapp config ssl create --hostname aopvdesign.usspapps.com -g {resource-group} --name app-aopvdesign
## output of this includes a thumbprint

## Not sure if I need this but I tried it in trying to make the next step work
az resource update --name {function_name} -g {resource-group} --namespace Microsoft.Web --resource-type sites --set properties.clientCertEnabled=true properties.clientCertMode=Optional
```

#### Problem command

```
az functionapp config ssl bind --certificate-thumbprint {thumbprint_from_previous} --name {function_name} -g {resource-group} --ssl-type SNI
```

I get Certificate for thumbprint '{thumbprint_from_previous}' not found.

For reference the thumbprint is 40 characters, starts with 3 digits and is just alphanumeric (no special characters).

When I run `az functionapp config ssl list -g {resource-group}` I get one certificate from another app but not the one I created.

If I go into the web portal I see that creation worked as I see this and I can bind it from here:
[image]

## Question reiterated

How can I use the cli to bind the cert, created with the cli, to the functionapp?

Answer (score 1):

I was on CLI version 2.37.0.

Updating to 2.57.0 fixed the issue that it couldn't bind. Doing the show command still fails but no biggie.